# ActiveRecord get average from group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to write this query in ActiveRecord 4, but to no avail.

```
SELECT date, AVG(gain) AS avg_gain FROM counters WHERE ( date > '2014-03-03'  ) GROUP BY date ORDER BY date DESC;
```

So I scrambled this together:

```
 Counter.select("date, AVG(gain) as avg_gain").where("date > '2014-03-03'").group(:date).order(date: :desc)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-04-01">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-31">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-30">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-29">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-28">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-27">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-26">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-25">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-24">, #<Counter id: nil, date: "2014-03-23">, ...]>
```

The only trouble is, the result does not contain `avg_gain` columns. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When you use `select`, the selected fields are added to the instances in the returned Relation.  The returned result does not include those selected fields in the printed output.

Access these fields just as you would access a column attribute:

```
result = Counter.select("date, AVG(gain) as avg_gain").where("date > '2014-03-03'").group(:date).order(date: :desc)
result.first.avg_gain # Prints expected value for the first Counter
```

Comment: Is there any way I could pluck it out? Like `Counter.select("date, AVG(gain) as avg_gain").where("date > '2014-03-03'").group(:date).order(date: :desc).pluck(:date, "avg_gain")`?

Comment: @JanNetherdrake you can do `result.map{ |counter| [ counter[:date], counter[:avg_gain] ] }` to return an array like `[ [date, avg], [date, avg], ... ]`

Answer (score 0):

OP wants to see [hash](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html) values for the items queried. Here are two options, but you should just use the first, the second is here as more of a warning or option when performance doesn't matter:

**I'd highly recommend this option, due to performance reasons:**

```
Counter.
    where("date > '2014-03-03'").
    group(:date).
    order(date: :desc).
    pluck("date, AVG(gain) as avg_gain").
    map { |date, avg_gain| {date: date, avg_gain: avg_gain} }
```

**The solution below looks nice but is about 10x slower. This is because `as_json` will instantiate a model object for every result:**

The Active Model JSON Serializer method, [`as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json) will also return an array of hashes. By default, each result will also include `"id"=>nil` if you don't use the `only:` `except:` option.

```
Counter.
    select("date, AVG(gain) as avg_gain").
    where("date > '2014-03-03'").
    group(:date).
    order(date: :desc).
    as_json(except: [:id])
```